# Comparing 2 Excel Worksheets and highlight deleted, changed or added with Comparable Interface (VB.net)

Tags: excel, vb.net

I'm a bloody beginner with Visual Basic and i just can't get behind it how to do it.
I need to add 2 excel files via a form and then show the differences in a new windows form.
This is how i did the first form:

```
Private Sub btnDatei1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDatei1.Click
    'OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "EXCEL Spreadsheet | *.xlsm |Excel Spreadsheet with macros | *.xlsx"      Funktioniert nicht

    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        txtDatei1.Text = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
        Worksheet1 = OpenFileDialog1.SafeFileName
    End If


End Sub

Private Sub btnDatei2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDatei2.Click
    If OpenFileDialog2.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        txtDatei2.Text = OpenFileDialog2.FileName
        Worksheet2 = OpenFileDialog2.SafeFileName
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnVergleich_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnVergleich.Click
    Form2.Show()
End Sub
```

Now i need to compare worksheet1 and worksheet2 with the comparable interface and i just don't even know how to start. I appreciate every help, thank you. You can also write hints in C#. Let me know if any infos are missing.

Comment: So what exactly about the two worksheets are you attempting to compare?  File attributes, columns, rows, cells, formats, values (and if so case sensitivity) or anything else?  There really is a whole lot more you need to explain here about what you want to achieve before anyone can give you any real hints.  Ans just beware, this isn't a code writing service, you need to give this compare algorithm a crack first

Comment: After deciding what want to compare, as someone else stated, you need to decide what you will use to open the Excel file to read the data.

Comment: What are you going to do with the FileName vs. the SafeFileName? Where are Worksheet1 and Worksheet2 declared? Worksheet is a terrible name for a String when you are working with Excel.

Answer (score 0):

I can provide you with code to read Excel sheets.

First of all, I am using an OpenFileDialog that I downloaded from Visual Studio's own Nuget package manager. With this OpenFileDialog, you simply have more options than the one which is already included. You also have to download the package `Microsoft.Office.Interop` from Nuget.

[image: download OFD and Excel package]

Second, you should be careful with MS Office products – you have to release the files with `Marshal.ReleaseComObject()`, otherwise you will not be able to edit them when you open them on the desktop. You would have to restart the PC.

Since you did not say exactly what you would like to compare and how, I simply created two Excel files and entered 7 measured values ​​in each. When the program reads in the numbers, these 7 values ​​are saved in a `List(of Double)`. A List(of ..) has the advantage that you can sort it later (by size, for example). It is a common way of storing data in a collective manner.

Another note on the side:
Be careful with Excel – I recently watched someone copying numbers in English notation (7.112) into a "German" Excel file, and he thought, “Why is it seven thousand one hundred and twelve?” Thus, I added `Deu As New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE")` so that it is at least defined for you.
The numbers are output on another WinForm (I've just subtracted them now).

[image: programm]

**Form1.vb**

```
Imports Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Dialogs
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Public NotInheritable Class FormMain
    Private xlApp As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    Private xlWorkBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
    Public MeaseringValues1 As New List(Of Double)
    Public MeaseringValues2 As New List(Of Double)
    Private Sub FormMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    End Sub

    Private Async Sub Button_read_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button_read.Click
        MeaseringValues1.Clear()
        MeaseringValues2.Clear()
        Await Task.Run(Sub() parseFile())
        If MeaseringValues1.Count = 0 Then Return

        Using FSD As New FormShowDifferences
            FSD.ShowDialog(Me)
        End Using
    End Sub

    Private Sub parseFile()
        Dim Path As String
        Using OFD1 As New CommonOpenFileDialog
            OFD1.Title = "Exceldatei auswählen"
            OFD1.Filters.Add(New CommonFileDialogFilter("Excel", ".xlsx"))
            OFD1.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
            Dim Result As CommonFileDialogResult
            Me.Invoke(Sub() Result = OFD1.ShowDialog())
            If Result = CommonFileDialogResult.Ok Then
                Path = OFD1.FileName
            Else
                Return
            End If
        End Using

        '–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
        ' File 1
        '–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––

        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Path)
        Dim xlWorkSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet = CType(xlWorkBook.Worksheets("Tabelle1"), Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)
        Dim xlRange As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange

        Dim ER As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range

        For rCnt As Integer = 1 To xlRange.Rows.Count Step 1
            ER = CType(xlRange.Cells(rCnt, 1), Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)
            MeaseringValues1.Add(CDbl(ER.Value))
        Next


        xlWorkBook.Save()
        xlWorkBook.Close()
        xlApp.Quit()


        '–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
        ' File 2
        '–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––

        Using OFD2 As New CommonOpenFileDialog
            OFD2.Title = "Exceldatei auswählen"
            OFD2.Filters.Add(New CommonFileDialogFilter("Excel", ".xlsx"))
            OFD2.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
            Dim Result As CommonFileDialogResult
            Me.Invoke(Sub() Result = OFD2.ShowDialog())
            If Result = CommonFileDialogResult.Ok Then
                Path = OFD2.FileName
            Else
                Return
            End If
        End Using

        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Path)
        Dim xlWorkSheet2 As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet = CType(xlWorkBook.Worksheets("Tabelle1"), Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)
        Dim xlRange2 As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range = xlWorkSheet2.UsedRange

        Dim ER2 As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range

        For rCnt As Integer = 1 To xlRange2.Rows.Count Step 1
            ER2 = CType(xlRange2.Cells(rCnt, 1), Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)
            MeaseringValues2.Add(CDbl(ER2.Value))
        Next


        xlWorkBook.Save()
        xlWorkBook.Close()
        xlApp.Quit()

        '–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
        ' clean up after yourself ;)
        '–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––

        If xlWorkSheet IsNot Nothing Then System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheet)
        If xlWorkSheet2 IsNot Nothing Then System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheet2)
        If xlWorkBook IsNot Nothing Then System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook)
        If xlApp IsNot Nothing Then System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp)
        xlApp = Nothing
        xlWorkBook = Nothing

    End Sub

    Private Sub FormMain_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
        If xlWorkBook IsNot Nothing Then xlWorkBook.Close()
        If xlApp IsNot Nothing Then xlApp.Quit()
    End Sub
End Class
```

**FormShowDifferences.vb**

```
Public NotInheritable Class FormShowDifferences
    Private ReadOnly Deu As New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE")
    Private Sub FormShowDifferences_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        For i As Integer = 0 To FormMain.MeaseringValues1.Count - 1 Step 1
            ListBox1.Items.Add(Math.Round(FormMain.MeaseringValues1(i) - FormMain.MeaseringValues2(i), 3).ToString(Deu))
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

I have also designed the read-in procedure asynchronously. That means it runs on a different thread than the GUI thread so your application won't freeze. This can be useful if the files are very large. For this little example with the 7 values, this is actually overdone. But that's how you've seen it once.
For things that are used to interact with the user, you then have to invoke. For example `Me.Invoke(Sub() Result = OFD2.ShowDialog())`; otherwise you'll get an exception "Crossthread operation not valid".